# Rails4: setting controller in sub-directory as root path in routes file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have an 'api' subdirectory in my controllers folder with a controller called todo_list_controller. I have been trying to set the index of this controller as the root path, but I keep getting the below error:

```
uninitialized constant TodoListController
```

below is an example of my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :todo_lists
  end

  root 'todo_list#index'
end
```

full error stacktrace:

```
uninitialized constant TodoListController

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `controller'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url      
Path Match
api_todo_lists_path GET /api/todo_lists(.:format)   api/todo_lists#index
POST    /api/todo_lists(.:format)   api/todo_lists#create
new_api_todo_list_path  GET /api/todo_lists/new(.:format)   api/todo_lists#new
edit_api_todo_list_path GET /api/todo_lists/:id/edit(.:format)  api/todo_lists#edit
api_todo_list_path  GET /api/todo_lists/:id(.:format)   api/todo_lists#show
PATCH   /api/todo_lists/:id(.:format)   api/todo_lists#update
PUT /api/todo_lists/:id(.:format)   api/todo_lists#update
DELETE  /api/todo_lists/:id(.:format)   api/todo_lists#destroy
root_path   GET /   todo_list#index
page_path   GET /pages/*id  high_voltage/pages#show
```

Comment: Can you post the full error stacktrace?

Comment: You missed the beginning part. The part from where it says `uninitialized constant ItemController`

Comment: sorry, just updated it

Comment: Is the error `uninitialized constant ItemController` or `uninitialized constant TodoListController`?

Comment: Ahh -_-, sorry about that was trying it out with a few other controllers, got a similar error. Have updated the above code for the todo_list_controller, should be consistent now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
root "todo_list#index"
```

rails will look for a file `app/controllers/todo_list_controller.rb` which contains the class `TodoListController`. Since I assume the controller already exists, in `api/todo_lists_controller.rb` you should be writing something like

```
root 'api/todo_lists#index'
```

Comment: it was a syntax error -_-'' (missing todo_lists not list). Thanks for the help,